# How to replace spaces from parameters in Fandom's Wikitext?

Tags: infobox, wikitext

I want to create an infobox template using Fandom's Wikitext that has data which links to Wikipedia. So, if someone uses the template like:

```
{{Person Infobox
| city=Los Angeles
}}
```

it would be display in the infobox as:
City: [Los Angeles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Los_Angeles)

I tried:

```
<infobox>
    <data source="city">
        <label>City</label>
        <format>[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/{{{city}}} {{{city}}}]</format>
    </data>
</infobox>
```

but the link breaks if the data has spaces.

How do I replace the spaces in `{{{city}}}` with `%20` or is it impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fandom help forum](https://community.fandom.com/f) is probably a better place for this type of questions, but there are two ways to do that:

**urlencode**

`[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/{{urlencode:{{{city}}}|PATH}} {{{city}}}]`

See https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words

**Interwiki link**

In this method you use double brackets and a pipe like in internal links:

`[[wikipedia:{{{city}}}|{{{city}}}]]`